# Get other columns for a React Accordion Web Part?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, react

Im using this tutorial
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-use-pnp-react-accordion-control-in-spfx/
to display items from an SPO list in a React Accordion.

It's hardcoded to use the columns "Title" and "Description"

Would it be possible to have two properties where users could specify the columns to use?

Thanks
P

```
    return (  
      <div className={styles.pnpReactAccordion}>  
        {  
          //Map list items and render in accordion  
          (this.state.listItems && this.state.listItems.length) ? this.state.listItems.map((item, index) => (  
            <Accordion title={item.Title} defaultCollapsed={true} className={"itemCell"} key={index}>  
              <div className={"itemContent"}>  
                <div className={"itemResponse"} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.Description }}></div>  
              </div>  
            </Accordion>  
          )) : <p>{this.state.errorMessage}</p>  
        }  
      </div>  
    );  
  }  



 interface IListItem { Id?: string; Question: string; Answer: string } export interface IReactAccordionState { listItems: IListItem[]; errorMessage: string; }


private async getListItems() { if (this.props.listName) { let items = await this._services.getListItems(this.props.listName, this.props.camlQuery); this.setState({ listItems: items }); } else { this.setState({ errorMessage: 'Please enter the list name in property pane configuration.' }); } }




SPService.ts

import { WebPartContext } from "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base";  
//import { sp } from '@pnp/sp/presets/all';  
import { spfi, SPFx } from "@pnp/sp";
import "@pnp/sp/webs";
import "@pnp/sp/lists";
import "@pnp/sp/items";
  

export class SPService {  
    constructor(private context: WebPartContext) {  
        // sp.setup({  
        //     spfxContext: this.context  
        // });  
    }  
  
    public async getListItems(listName: string, camlQuery: string) {  
        try {  
            // let listItems: any[] = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listName)  
            //     .items  
            //     .select("Id,Title,Description")  
            //     .get();  
            // return listItems;  

            const sp = spfi().using(SPFx(this.context));

            //const items: any[] = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listName).items();
            
            //const items: any[] = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listName).getItemsByCAMLQuery({
            //  ViewXml: `<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Category"></FieldRef><Value Type="Text">Choice 1</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>`,

            const items: any[] = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listName).getItemsByCAMLQuery({
             //ViewXml: `<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Category"></FieldRef><Value Type="Text">Choice 1</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>`,
               ViewXml: camlQuery,

          });

            console.log(items);
            return items;
        } catch (err) {  
            Promise.reject(err);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Yes. this is possible. You can create two property in web part property pane and adjust your code accordingly. Follow https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/basics/integrate-with-property-pane  link to add web part property pane

Comment: Thanks I try to do this but it doesn't like it ... <Accordion title={item[this.props.headerColumn]} defaultCollapsed={true} className={"itemCell"} key={index}>  
              <div className={"itemContent"}>  
                <div className={"itemResponse"} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.Answer }}></div>  
              </div>  
            </Accordion>

Comment: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'IListItem'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'IListItem'.ts(7053)

Comment: But it is fine with ... <Accordion title={item["Question"]} defaultCollapsed={true} className={"itemCell"} key={index}>

Comment: Could you please share a code for State interface and also code which you are using to get items from SharePoint list to get more idea?

Comment: @KalpeshVaghela thanks for your help. Here you go. interface IListItem {  
  Id?: string;  
  Question: string;  
  Answer: string  
}  

export interface IReactAccordionState {  
  listItems: IListItem[];  
  errorMessage: string;  
}

Comment: private async getListItems() {  
    if (this.props.listName) {  
      let items = await this._services.getListItems(this.props.listName, this.props.camlQuery);  
      this.setState({ listItems: items });  
    }  
    else {  
      this.setState({ errorMessage: 'Please enter the list name in property pane configuration.' });  
    }  
  }

Comment: Please update original question rather than adding your code in comment so that it would be more clear and also share code interface for IListItem

Comment: done thanks. sorry about that,

Comment: You should also share this._services.getListItems method because here you are not passing this.props.headerColumn  and also other column.. so still it is not enough information to help you here.  Have you create two two web part properties and passed it in your component in the React Component?

Comment: getListItems is in the original question thanks

Comment: I didn't mean getListItems but I meant this._services.getListItems which is being called from getListItems method

Comment: I have added SPService.ts thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update getListItems method as below:

```
private async getListItems() {
    if (this.props.listName) {
      const listItems = await this._services.getListItems(this.props.listName, this.props.camlQuery);
      const items = new Array<IListItem>();
      for (let index = 0; index < listItems.length; index++) {
        const item = listItems[index];
        items.push({
          Id: item["ID"],
          Question:item[this.props.headerColumn],
          Answer: item[this.props.descriptionColumn]
        });        
      }
      this.setState({ listItems: items });
    }
    else {
      this.setState({ errorMessage: 'Please enter the list name in property pane configuration.' });
    }
  }
```

I took the assumption here that **this.props.headerColumn** and **this.props.descriptionColumn** will be password from parent from web part property configuration.

Update IListItem interface to export it so that we can use it in another field. Add "export" line before interface as shown in below

```
 export interface IListItem { Id?: string; Question: string; Answer: string } export interface IReactAccordionState { listItems: IListItem[]; errorMessage: string; }
```

Update import statement in the file where you have written getItems method.

```
import { IPnpReactAccordionState, IListItem } from './IPnpReactAccordionState';
```

Then you can update your render method as below:

```
return (  
  <div className={styles.pnpReactAccordion}>  
    {  
      //Map list items and render in accordion  
      (this.state.listItems && this.state.listItems.length) ? this.state.listItems.map((item, index) => (  
        <Accordion title={item.Question} defaultCollapsed={true} className={"itemCell"} key={index}>  
          <div className={"itemContent"}>  
            <div className={"itemResponse"} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.Answer }}></div>  
          </div>  
        </Accordion>  
      )) : <p>{this.state.errorMessage}</p>  
    }  
  </div>  
);
```

Comment: Thanks. On the line const items = new Array<IListItem>(); it says Cannot find name IListItem

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly

Comment: You are a star. Thanks so much.